# Which power source(16A or 6A) should i use for my laptop charging having adaper input 2.5A & output 6.7A?

Tags: laptop, charging, dell-xps

I'm using a Dell adapter:

- Input: 100-240V~2.5A(2,5A) 50-60Hz
- Output: 19.5V(19,5V)==6.7A(6,7A)

I always connect it to 230V 50Hz 16A in my home and 6A in my office.

Is it safe for my laptop? Please comment your views.

Answer (score 1):

As long as your adapter input rating matches what comes out of the socket, you should be fine.

- The electric potential (volt) of the socket should be within the range of the adapter input (230 is between 110-240).
- The frequency should likewise fall within the adapter input range.
- The input current of the adapter should not exceed the rated output of the socket. In your case the input is 2,5A (@230V), the rating of the socket is 6A, so you should be fine. In the case the socket rating would not be sufficient a circuit breaker should pop (because you are exceeding the maximum rating, resulting in a fire risk).